# Is there a good way to work with Indesign justification settings?

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, formatting, paragraph

I don't find it very intuitive, and I haven't found a clear guide online as yet.

I end up "playing" with Word Spacing until I get to an approximation of what I need.

I only ever modify Word Spacing and Letter Spacing.

For Letter Spacing I always use -5% minimum and +5% maximum,
For Word Spacing it is a crapshoot between 10% minimum and 200% maximum and many varying numbers in between.

It's a pain, it takes ages, and I'm sure I can't be doing this correctly.. Does anyone have any pointers how this is best acheived? Many thanks if so.

Comment: From my experience it's really personal preference combined with the font you are using and how you want the final layout.  But I only dabble in large layouts.

Comment: Those are some pretty extreme numbers to me. I virtually never go beyond -2%/+1% and 98%/102%. Anything more and you end up with terribly squished letters and words, in my experience.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys.  

I've applied those settings to my text and that looks far more sensible Janus, many thanks. I'll keep within those ranges - for my sanity as much as display of final output...!

Kind regards

Comment: 10% minimum word space is *way* too small. From memory, I think I use 50%–150% (but note that InDesign does not treat these as absolute values to stick to but merely as "normal", and it will happily go beyond them and only show such a line as "spacing violation" when asked to).